# How to change color of all edits to red in word? I dont want to switch back to red each time I make an edit

Tags: editing, microsoft-word

I am editing an existing doc, I want to make all my edit as red (or any different color). What I am doing right now, I made edit and then reach out to fonts and change color each time I change something, is there a simpler way so my edit automatically goes in red. Tracking is already ON in word document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change the track changes color](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/change-the-track-changes-color-48c80bb3-458c-4abb-8e21-25f9bac47484) from Microsoft says:

1. Go to **Review** > **Tracking Dialog Launcher**.
2. Select **Advanced Options**.
3. Select the arrows next to the **Color** boxes and the **Comments** box, and choose **By author**. You can also color-code text moves and changes made to table cells.

Comment: Thanks this is close but not really what I wanted, which probably is not possibe. This technique works but you have to be in "review mode", where you can see all the bubbles, comments etc. What I wanted was simply change the color of my edits, without going into review mode explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The method depends on which version of Microsoft Word you use, but what you want to do is find the [Advanced Track Changes Options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-track-changes-color-48c80bb3-458c-4abb-8e21-25f9bac47484) menu. In it you can set your default color, but note other people who open your file will not necessarily see the same. For them the color is still chosen at random. Good to keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks was helpful but did not quite work for me but now I know this is probably not possible. I wanted text to highlight without goign to "review mode". This solution works if you doublt click on changes and it then enters into review mode.